# How to read and match across multiple lines with python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to extract pertinent information from a large textfile (1000+ lines), most of which isn't important:

```
 ID: 67108866 Virtual-system: root, VPN Name: VPN-NAME-XYZ
  Local Gateway: 1.1.1.1, Remote Gateway: 2.2.2.2
  Traffic Selector Name: TS-1
  Local Identity: ipv4(10.10.10.0-10.10.10.255)
  Remote Identity: ipv4(10.20.10.0-10.20.10.255)
  Version: IKEv2
  DF-bit: clear, Copy-Outer-DSCP Disabled, Bind-interface: st0.287
  Port: 500, Nego#: 0, Fail#: 0, Def-Del#: 0 Flag: 0x2c608b29 
  Multi-sa, Configured SAs# 1, Negotiated SAs#: 1 
  Tunnel events:
```

From this I need to extract only certain bits, and example output would be something like:

```
VPN Name: VPN-NAME-XYZ, Local Gateway: 1.1.1.1, Remote Gateway: 2.2.2.2
```

I've tried a couple different ways to get this, however my code keeps stopping on the 1st match, I need the code to match 1 line, then move onto the following line and match that:

```
with open('/path/to/vpn.txt', 'r') as file:
    for vpn in file:
        vpn = vpn.strip().lower()
        name = "xyz"
        if name in vpn:
            print(vpn)
            if "1.1.1.1" in vpn:
                print(vpn)
```

I'm able to print both if I move the 2nd if in line:

```
with open('/path/to/vpn.txt', 'r') as file:
    for vpn in file:
        vpn = vpn.strip().lower()
        name = "xyz"
        if name in vpn:
            print(vpn)
        if "1.1.1.1" in vpn:
            print(vpn)
```

Is it possible to match clauses on both lines?
I've tried a few different ways, with my indents and matches but can't get it, also the problem with `print(vpn)` is it's printing the entire line

Comment: Since you're stepping through the file line by line, you can't match the whole thing at once. It'll depend a bit on the rest of the input file as to what is the most efficient way to read and match the input.

Comment: Do you really want to match on "1.1.1.1", and not on "Gateway"? It would seem to me that the IP is more variable than the term, and thus the Gateway term may be better to match on. Same question for "xyz", which again is a (variable) name fo the VPN, not the VPN indicator.

Comment: Do you know whether the VPN name and the IP address lines are always consecutive, i.e., the second always directly follows the first one?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, the 1.1.1.1 will denominate the originating zone, where Gateway will show all zones, i need to distinguish which VPNs originate where then get their name and remote IP, the lines will always follow the same pattern as above, but they won't be consecutive for e.g. 10,20,30 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to match the regions you need and then get all matched from the entire text. You need not do this line by line as well. An example below.

```
import re
found_text = []
with open('/path/to/vpn.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_text = file.read()
    [found_text.extend(found.split(",")) for found in [finds.group(0) for finds in
                                                       re.finditer(
                                                           r"((VPN Name|Local Gateway|Remote Gateway):.*)",
                                                           file_text)]]
    # split by comma, if you want it to be splitted further

print(found_text)
```

This will yield an output like

```
['VPN Name: VPN-NAME-XYZ', 'Local Gateway: 1.1.1.1', ' Remote Gateway: 2.2.2.2']
```

Comment: Thanks Kris, with your suggestion I'm close, however this is giving me all VPNs, is there a way i can change "Local Gateway" with the actual IP "1.1.1.1", currently if i do it removes the "Local Gateway" field all together.
In summary I have 300+ VPNs, from different zones, i need to be able to seperate these if possible, maybe save my output as another variable and iterate over this?